# Json array without a name into FlatList via redux

Tags: json, react-native, redux, axios, react-native-flatlist

So I'm tying to retrieve a json file via an API and I've been successful following the indications [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/comprehensive-guide-to-using-redux-in-react-native/). After minors changes, it worked fine with the movieDB.

It starts like this:

```
export const getMovies = () => {
  try {
    return async dispatch => {
      const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`);
      if (res.data) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_MOVIES,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Unable to fetch');
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // Add custom logic to handle errors
  }
};
```

Then gets passed into the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  movies: [],
  favorites: [],
};

function moviesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MOVIES:
      return {...state, cards: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And the store:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  moviesReducer,
});
```

Finally, I'm rendering it into a FlatList:

```
export default function BooksList() {

  const {movies} = useSelector(state => state.moviesReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchMovies = () => dispatch(getMovies());
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 44, paddingHorizontal: 20}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 22}}>Popular Movies</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 12}}>
        <FlatList
          data={movies.results}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <View style={{marginVertical: 12}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
                  <View style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: 12}}>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={{fontSize: 22, paddingRight: 16}}>
                        {item.name}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={item => item.code.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And this works fine.

Now in this API output, the array is named 'results'.

```
{"page":1,"results":[{"adult":false,"backdrop_path": ... }]}
```

The array I actually want to render has no name. The API returns:

```
[{"pack_code":"Core","pack_name": ...}]
```

I've been trying, very naively:

```
<FlatList
  data={movies} // changed the data name here
  renderItem={({item}) => { ...

    );
  }}
  keyExtractor={item => item.code.toString()}
/>
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to name the array and render it in the FlatList?

Comment: Your changes in FlatList should be fine. The issue is in the `moviesReducer`, the case for `GET_MOVIES` should return states update with `movies` instead of `cards`.